# Code Geass season 1 episode 7, there is a song playing at 16:56

Tags: music, code-geass

In Code Geass season 1 episode 7, there is a song playing at 16:56. I can't find the song no matter where I look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "Stream of Consciousness" (track 4 from [the first OST](http://vgmdb.net/album/19057)). Here is a thirty-second extract from the beginning of the track: https://clyp.it/qupf3tgv.